# Checkbox props change allthough a preventDefault is calles

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to get a 3-way checkbox to work.
For this, I want to handle the click or change action myself... ie decide what the next state will be.

But I struggle at the very begin:

- I initialize a checkbox
- Set the indeterminate true
- Check this runtime => indeterminate=true, checked=false
- Got an event handler for a click with a `prevenDefault()`
- The markup stays unchanged as expected => looks like an indeterminate checkbox
- But when I check the values for indeterminate and checked they have toggled none the less

Googling for a solution I found that there are 2 ways to create an event handler

```
$('.chk').click(function(event){});
```

And

```
$('.chk').on('click',function(event){});
```

I tried both.
Also tried to change instead of click.
Even tried having both click and change, with one of them just having the `prevenDefault()`.

I've got a jsfiddle set up:

https://jsfiddle.net/PeterKaagman/rpmL0gv4

```js
$(".chk").prop("indeterminate", true);
$("#out").append("Checked "       + $('#chk_1').prop('checked') + "<br>");
$("#out").append("Indeterminate " + $('#chk_1').prop('indeterminate') );

$(".chk").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  $("#out").empty();
  console.log(this);
  $("#out").append("Checked "       + this.checked + "<br>");
  $("#out").append("Indeterminate " + this.indeterminate );
});

//$(".chk").on(change,function(event){
//  event.preventDefault();
//})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>3-way checkbox</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="chk_1" >
<div id="out"></div>
```

Most of it is for debugging as you can see.

What I expected was that the properties checked and indeterminate would not change due to the preventDefault(). Letting me decide the next state of the checkbox.

I'm sure I doing something stupid... could someone plz point it out for me?

Peter

Comment: You are trying to use a delegate event listener incorrectly.  `on(event, childSelector, callback)` is the correct form.  The event is always passed into the callback, not on the `on()` method

Comment: Also given that you are binding on the element that is clicked, you don't use a delegate event listener in this case.

Comment: Also should be seeing errors in browser dev tools console from code shown. Always mention specific errors

Comment: Forgot to mention: When I check "this" in the console the properties have not changed.

Comment: @Taplar: delegate event handler?

Comment: @Taplar: did try the on(event.childSelektor,callback) method like I mentioned... did not work

Comment: @charlietfl what errors do you mean? there are no errors in the console

Comment: S.O. post about delegate event listeners: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Peter that comment was written before you edited the incorrect syntax

Comment: @charlietfl I did notice some errors.... did edit the fiddle and message... sorry bout that

Comment: @Taplar about indeterminate: https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/ chrome and firefox render it just fine, will read up on delegate event handlers

Comment: @Taplar the checkbox is static... its not added dynamicly

Comment: All my statements in regards to delegate event listeners stem from your original post containing an invalid `on()` declaration.  I'm not telling you to use them.

Comment: @taplar my bad in that case... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.preventDefault()` is preventing the "normal behavior" of the checkbox being checked or unchecked... But it seems like it does not affect the checkbox properties... Which are changed anyway. Your snippet proves that.

> What I expected was that the properties checked and indeterminate would not change...

I would have too! I didn't know... And I can't explain why that is. So, in my opinion, that's a very good question! But I think I found the way to walk-around that *issue*...

The trick is to store the checkbox state on `mousedown`. That's before the properties change. On `click`, which is occuring right after... Restore thoses properties.

Then do what you like...

```js
$(".chk").prop("indeterminate", true);
$("#out").append("Checked "       + $('#chk_1').prop('checked') + "<br>");
$("#out").append("Indeterminate " + $('#chk_1').prop('indeterminate') );


var checkbox_state_on_mousedown = {};
$(".chk").on("mousedown click",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if(event.type=="mousedown"){
    // Store checkbox state before the click changes them
    checkbox_state_on_mousedown = {
      checked:this.checked,
      indeterminate:this.indeterminate
    };
    // Stop the handler's execution here
    return;
  }
  
  
  $("#out").empty();
  console.log(this);
  $("#out").append("<b>On mousedown:</b><br>");
  $("#out").append("Checked "       + checkbox_state_on_mousedown.checked + "<br>");
  $("#out").append("Indeterminate " + checkbox_state_on_mousedown.indeterminate);
  $("#out").append("<br><br>");
  
  $("#out").append("<b>On click:</b><br>");
  $("#out").append("Checked "       + this.checked + "<br>");
  $("#out").append("Indeterminate " + this.indeterminate );
  $("#out").append("<br><br>");
  
  // Restore the "before click" properties
  $(this).prop(checkbox_state_on_mousedown);
  
  $("#out").append("<b>Properties restored:</b><br>");
  $("#out").append("Checked "       + this.checked + "<br>");
  $("#out").append("Indeterminate " + this.indeterminate );
  
  // Do what you like with the restored properties from here...
  // ...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>3-way checkbox</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="chk_1" >
<div id="out"></div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/pen?editors=1010)

Comment: I did read that a comment is not intended for a thank you. But that seems crude to me. So @Louys I say thank you [bow]. Thank you for proving me not being crazy... thank you for a nice workaround, did not come up with the mouse down solution. My little project can go on